# Cheap switch 125V 5A fuse blew

Tags: fuses

Cheap switch glass fuse blew, 125V 5A. Found a 125V 8A fuse in a string of Christmas lights. Can I use it to replace 125V 5A?

Answer (score 4):

**No. You can't.** The rest of the system is expecting the fuse to blow at 5A. Your new fuse will blow at 8A, which means it will pass 6A through without any problem which could cause the downstream circuits to be destroyed or catch fire since they're not expecting that.